# Haskell - Is Fold polymorphic function?

Tags: haskell

A function is *polymorphic* if it works for *several different types* - and thus, a function is *monomorphic* if it works only for *one type*. ([wiki.haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism))

As an example, `map` is polymorphic.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

However, the function (`foo`) has a *monomorphic* type. It will only accept lists of `Int`:

```
foo :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
foo = map
```

`foldr` in Haskell:

```
foldr f z []     = z 
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Is `Fold` polymorphic function too?

Comment: Generally speaking, `fold` is a pattern that allow to traverse the elements of different collections. In the case of `foldr`, it's applied to lists of any type. So in this sense, it's a polymorphic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, `fold` is a pattern that allows to traverse the elements of different collections. In the case of `foldr`, it's applied to lists of any type:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So in this sense, it's a polymorphic function.

Comment: Indeed the type is even more inclusive than that in GHC 7.10+ (I believe that's the right version), since `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, i.e. any type of foldable can be folded, not just lists.

Comment: Yeah, I just remembered `foldr`'s type from my college class, I don't have `GHCi` to peek its actual type, just wanted to remark the idea. It's better to point that out though, thanks.

Comment: Even if `foldr` were still restricted to lists, strictly speaking it is still a function from `a -> b -> b` to `b -> [a] -> b`. The domain is still universally qualified even if the codomain isn't (completely) so.

Answer (score 2):

You could ask Haskell itself, via GHCi:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

As you can see, it's defined entirely from parametrically polymorphic types (`a`, `b`, and `t`, where `t` is `Foldable`).